# How to set the default datatype as 'float32' for numpy & pandas?

Tags: numpy, type-conversion, pandas

My machine's RAM is 3G on Windows XP and 'float32' data's precision is enough for my current application (based on Pandas 0.10 + NumPy 1.6.2). So I want to reset the default floating datatype to `'float32'` instead of `'float64'` to reduce the memory usage. How to do that ? (I know I can explictly put `dtype = 'float32'` in functions, but i just want a global setting)

And is there any bad side-effect if I do so ? (calculation speed, compatible of interacting with other modules, future upgrading etc..)

Comment: I don't think there will be, at least according to these questions. Interesting question though.

Comment: Follow [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5351486/832621) to a related question that also solves your problem. Other related questions: -[Python: Making numpy default to float32](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721831/python-making-numpy-default-to-float32) -[Floating point precision in Python array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5160339/floating-point-precision-in-python-array)