# Specifying default dtype for np.array(1.)

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a way to specify default dtype that's used with constructs like `np.array(1.)`?

In particular I want `np.array(1.)` to be `np.float32` and `np.array(1)` to be `np.int32`. Instead I'm getting `np.float64` and `np.int64`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The default depends on your system. On a 64-bit system, default types will be 64-bit. On a 32-bit system, default types will be 32-bit. There is no way to change the default short of re-compiling numpy with a different system C header.

You can of course specify dtypes explicitly, e.g.

```
>>> x = np.array(1, dtype='int32')
```

Edit: as kazemakase mentions below, the above is only true for int32/int64. In recent numpy versions, the default for floating-point is float64 regardless of the system.

Comment: OK, looks like numpy wasn't ready for GPU age. Systems nowadays are 64-bit, but GPU computation is done mainly in 32-bit, so we are ending up with people doing suboptimal thing by propagating default numpy type to GPU

Answer (score 3):

You could use `np.float32` or `np.int32` as `np.ndarray` constructor:

```
>>> np.float32([1.])
array([ 1.], dtype=float32)
>>> np.int32([1])
array([1], dtype=int32)
```

but that returns a numpy-scalar if given a scalar input (not a rank 0 array):

```
>>> np.float32(1)
1.
>>> np.asarray(np.float32(1))  # Use np.asarray to convert it to an array
array(1.0, dtype=float32)
```

Redefining the default dtype seems to be not so easy, see also:

- [How to set the default datatype as 'float32' for numpy & pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15674815/how-to-set-the-default-datatype-as-float32-for-numpy-pandas)
- [Can i set float128 as the standard float-array in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350342/can-i-set-float128-as-the-standard-float-array-in-numpy)
- [Python: Making numpy default to float32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721831/python-making-numpy-default-to-float32)

If you don't care additional overhead you can always use a dictionary as "switch" to get correct dtype for those you find inappropriate:

```
defaults = {np.dtype('int64'): np.int32,
            np.dtype('float64'): np.float32}

before = 1.
np.array(before, dtype=defaults.get(np.result_type(before), None))
```

This will however fail with complicated types like characters (strings) or objects.

Answer (score 0):

I just use a set of simple wrapper functions like this:

```
def np_array(shape):
    return np.array(shape, dtype=np.float32)

def np_zeros(shape):
    return np.zeros(shape, dtype=np.float32)
    
def np_ones(shape):
    return np.ones(shape, dtype=np.float32)

etc...
```

Then just substitute calls to e.g. "np.array(..." with "np_array(..."