# PyTorch: Infer dtype from device capability, not input data

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I am trying to write a device-agnostic library for PyTorch, and I have stumbled across the problem of PyTorch using dtypes that are not compatible with my compute device:

```
import scipy.signal
import torch

raw_window = scipy.signal.windows.cosine(128)
print(raw_window.dtype)  # float64

device = torch.device("cpu")
window = torch.as_tensor(raw_window, device=device)
print(window.device)  # cpu
print(window.dtype)   # torch.float64

device = torch.device("cuda")
window = torch.as_tensor(raw_window, device=device)
print(window.device)  # cuda:0
print(window.dtype)   # torch.float64
```

As you can see in the last line, torch assigns the dtype `torch.float64`, even though my CUDA device is not able to handle double precision float values.

Is there a way to make PyTorch use the most suitable device dtype instead of the input data dtype? Or am I misunderstanding that whole concept of setting devices and dtypes completely?

Answer (score 0):

No, as you noticed PyTorch infers `dtype` from `input` data only.

In your case, as `numpy` has it's default set to `np.float64` (regardless of system and architecture) PyTorch will infer it's analogous `torch.float64`, so it's more of a problem with starting from `numpy` (and [you can't set different default `dtype`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36635238/specifying-default-dtype-for-np-array1)).

In `pytorch` you usually go for `torch.float32` (and it is the default), eventually `torch.float16` for mixed precision (leaving out quantization). Usually such precision is sufficient (not sure about your exact use-case though).

Your best bet is hence to `cast` `numpy` arrays to `np.float32` like this:

```
raw_window = raw_window.astype(np.float32)
```

(or cast it via `pytorch` or even better create `float32` from the beginning),
which AFAIK should be available on all/most devices be it CPU or GPU.

For CPU/GPU agnostic approach you should go for explicit device creation [as shown here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/cuda.html#device-agnostic-code):

```
if not args.disable_cuda and torch.cuda.is_available():
    args.device = torch.device('cuda')
else:
    args.device = torch.device('cpu')
```

(extend if you need to explicitly specify `cuda` or a-like) and use it during `tensor` creation.

Comment: Your last remark is a little bit redundant as that is exactly what I am doing already.

Comment: @NilsWerner So i thought, but better redundant and too explicit than too implicit