# Assigning float as a dictionary key changes its precision (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, floating-point

I have a list of floats (actually it's a pandas Series object, if it changes anything) which looks like this:

```
mySeries:

...
22      16.0
23      14.0
24      12.0
25      10.0
26       3.1
...
```

(So elements of this Series are on the right, indices on the left.) Then I'm trying to assign the elements from this Series as keys in a dictionary, and indices as values, like this:

```
{ mySeries[i]: i for i in mySeries.index }
```

and I'm getting pretty much what I wanted, except that...

```
{ 6400.0: 0, 66.0: 13, 3.1000000000000001: 23, 133.0: 10, ... }
```

Why has `3.1` suddenly changed into `3.1000000000000001`? I guess this has something to do with the way the floating point numbers are represented (?) but why does it happen *now* and how do I avoid/fix it?

**EDIT:** Please feel free to suggest a better title for this question if it's inaccurate.

**EDIT2:** Ok, so it seems that it's the exact same number, just *printed* differently. Still, if I assign `mySeries[26]` as a dictionary key and then I try to run:

```
myDict[mySeries[26]]
```

I get `KeyError`. What's the best way to avoid it?

Comment: did you try MySeries.astype(float).to_dict()

Comment: @StevenG I'm trying to do this the other way around: to have indices as values. Anyway, I don't think it would solve this problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The dictionary isn't changing the floating point representation of 3.1, but it is actually displaying the full precision. Your print of mySeries[26] is truncating the precision and showing an approximation.

You can prove this:

```
pd.set_option('precision', 20)
```

Then view mySeries.

```
0    16.00000000000000000000
1    14.00000000000000000000
2    12.00000000000000000000
3    10.00000000000000000000
4     3.10000000000000008882
dtype: float64
```

**EDIT**:

[What every  computer programmer should know about floating point arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) is always a good read.

**EDIT**:

Regarding the KeyError, I was not able to replicate the problem.

```
>> x = pd.Series([16,14,12,10,3.1])
>> a = {x[i]: i for i in x.index}
>> a[x[4]]
4
>> a.keys()
[16.0, 10.0, 3.1000000000000001, 12.0, 14.0]
>> hash(x[4])
2093862195
>> hash(a.keys()[2])
2093862195
```

Answer (score 6):

The value is already that way in the Series:

```
>>> x = pd.Series([16,14,12,10,3.1])
>>> x
0    16.0
1    14.0
2    12.0
3    10.0
4     3.1
dtype: float64
>>> x.iloc[4]
3.1000000000000001
```

This has to do with floating point precision:

```
>>> np.float64(3.1)
3.1000000000000001
```

See [Floating point precision in Python array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5160339/floating-point-precision-in-python-array) for more information about this.

Concerning the `KeyError` in your edit, I was not able to reproduce. See the below:

```
>>> d = {x[i]:i for i in x.index}
>>> d
{16.0: 0, 10.0: 3, 12.0: 2, 14.0: 1, 3.1000000000000001: 4}
>>> x[4]
3.1000000000000001
>>> d[x[4]]
4
```

My suspicion is that the `KeyError` is coming from the `Series`: what is `mySeries[26]` returning?

Comment: Thanks @brianpck, you're right, the problem was indeed caused by something else in my code (unrelated to floating point representation). Pandas Series works fine.

Comment: @machaerus If I were you, I'd edited the question to indicate that the key error turned out to be unrelated to the precision issue.